# Flutter: Widget not rebuilt when using setstate with AnimatedSwitcher

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a question about RadioListTile and Radio in Flutter.
When using RadioListTile together with AnimatedSwitcher it is not possible to select the radiobuttons.

The error lies in this line:

```
 Widget pageTest;

 @override
 initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageTest = thirdSurveyPage();
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: AnimatedSwitcher(
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), child: pagetest));
 }
```

If I do it as such:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), child: thirdSurveyPage()));
  }
```

the selection of radiobuttons works.
I need to use the first method in order to be able to use the AnimatedSwitcher widget, the code snippet only shows one snippet of three since the other two are working properly.

I narrowed it down to the widget "thirdSurveyPage" apparently not being rebuilt when using the first method but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/mstachalski/pen/ZEbOPNa

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
`thirdSurveyPage()` is a function, so you can use `Function pageTest` not `Widget pageTest`

code snippet

```
Function pageTest;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageTest = thirdSurveyPage;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");
    return Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), child: pageTest()));
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SurveyPageState1();
  }
}

class _SurveyPageState1 extends State<MyWidget> {
  int rating1 = 0;
  int rating2 = 0;
  int rating3 = 0;
  int rating4 = 0;
  int rating5 = 0;
  String _answerQ6 =
      "Was andere Besucher vermutlich denken, wenn ich mich entscheide zu dieser Bar zu gehen";

  Function pageTest;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageTest = thirdSurveyPage;
  }

  Map<int, String> questions = {
    11: "1. Mit der BarBachelor-App bin ich:",
    12: "2. Wenn ich beim nächsten Event die Wahl habe, möchte ich diese App noch einmal verwenden.",
    13: "3. Die Infos zu jeder Bar waren zuverlässig",
    14: "4. Es war schwierig sich zu entscheiden, zu welcher Bar man als nächstes geht.",
    15: "5. Ich finde die BarBachelor-App nützlich.",
    16: "6. Was bedeuten die Handsymbole bei jeder Bar?",
  };

  ///This doesnt work
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");
    return Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), child: pageTest()));
  }

  Widget thirdSurveyPage() {
    return Container(
      key: ValueKey(3),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32)),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              RadioListTile<String>(
                title: const Text(
                    'Was andere Besucher vermutlich denken, wenn ich mich entscheide zu dieser Bar zu gehen.'),
                value:
                    "Was andere Besucher vermutlich denken, wenn ich mich entscheide zu dieser Bar zu gehen.",
                groupValue: _answerQ6,
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _answerQ6 = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile<String>(
                title: const Text("Wie gut die Stimmung in dieser Bar ist."),
                value: "Wie gut die Stimmung in dieser Bar ist.",
                groupValue: _answerQ6,
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _answerQ6 = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    child: Text(
                      "Test einreichen",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      print(_answerQ6);
                    }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```